# 「を」Vてある - Typo or actual construction?

Tags: grammar, particles, verbs

Seen in the introduction to a book entitled 日本語文法ハンドブック, so it would greatly surprise me if it's a typo.  Each section in the book is broken into parts and one is entitled "これだけは", being described here:

「これだけは」にはその項目を教えるにあたって最低限知っておくべき情報を挙げてあります。

The end of the sentence is a Vてある construction, but uses を instead of が or は.  My understanding is that this is not correct.  Is this a typo, or a usage I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41624/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

が～Vてある is used to describe a state that comes from completing ***V***. を~Vてある is used to indicate that ***V*** has been completed in preparation for something. In your case, it's that the information has been provided for your edification.

The table from [here](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/046.html) helps show the two usages of Vてある (though I think it's wrong that ~Vている can only be for intransitive verbs):
[image: てあります]

And here are some examples, pulled from [here](https://www.tomojuku.com/blog/teoku/tearu2/) and the previous link:

> たくさん漢字の練習**をしてある**から、今日のテストは問題ないと思う。
>
> A：小林さんに来週の予定**を話してあります**か。B：いいえ、まだです。

Comment: I could not read the Japanese in this table. Would you mind explaining it in English?

Comment: @max I assume you can read the first row so I'll ignore that for now. The first column says: "Types of verbs", "Description of current state", "work that is done on purpose". "Types of verbs" for Vてあります says "Transitive Verbs that cause change in the target" and  "Types of verbs" for Vています says "Intransitive verbs that indicate the subject changed". The circles and xs are typical tablular things indicating yes/no respectively.